# How to prevent slow match / match_phrase queries for keywords in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, keyword-search, elasticsearch-analyzers

How can I achieve that a `match` query for certain fields is equivalent to a `term` query?

I have a larger index in Elastic covering events. Each event has an `eventid` field consisting of a random hex string (e.g. `f4fc38c993c1a8273f9c40eedc9050b7`) as well as some other fields. The `eventid` is indexed as `keyword` in Elastic.

If I query based on this field in Kibana, the query often runs into timeouts, because Kibana automatically generates a `match` query for `eventid:f4fc38c993c1a8273f9c40eedc9050b7`.

If I set a manual filter using `{ "query": { "term": { "eventid": "f4fc38c993c1a8273f9c40eedc9050b7" } } }` (so a `term` instead of `match` query) I get a response quite quickly.

From my understanding, these should be pretty much equivalent, as `keyword` fields aren't analyzed, so the `match` query should be equivalent to a `term` query.

What am I missing?

Comment: The field being a keyword only means that it is not analyzed prior to indexing. Nothing should change during an actual query. However, both queries should be roughly similar. Maybe Kibana is computing something else, do you have the exact query sent by Kibana ?